Jupyter not releasing manim animations when updated, generating `PermissionError`
I'm a beginner, iterating on a video idea in jupyter and hitting an annoying error.
Every so often a video fails with a PermissionError:
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'media\\jupyter\\Test12 . . . 

As you can see, I'm currently fixing by incrementing the object name Test##.  Even deleting the video from the indicated folder doesn't relaease the name (and in any case windows doesn't let me in many cases, saying the file is in use by python).
The signature I'm using is based on an online example I found, but it's fairly simple:
%%manim -qm Test12 

I've checked and the target folder isn't synced with any clouds (Can't find the question that suggested that, was a PIL question).
Am I missing something as far as getting jupyter to release the mp4 files when it's being updated?
